# Remove all views from activity

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, view, xamarin.forms

I use method AddContentView for add my view in Activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
    LoadApplication (new App());
    this.AddContentView (myView, layoutPararms);
}

protected override void OnBackPressed ()
{
    this.RemoveAllViews() //this method does not contain in Activity
}
```

I press 'back' button and open my application many times.
The memory overflows because I add view in Activity every time in OnCreate method.
How can I remove all views from activity?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use AddContentView in OnCreate because LoadApplication already does.

Comment: No, this project contains AddContentView and I must remove all views from activity